# ENFILE: File Table Overflow with Karma

Tags: javascript, gulp, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, isparta

I am getting a **file table overflow** issue while running the Karma tests, and I have no clue how to debug this.

**karma.conf.js:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ['jspm', 'jasmine'],
        files: [

            'node_modules/karma-babel-preprocessor/node_modules/babel-core/browser-polyfill.js',
            'node_modules/jasmine-async-sugar/jasmine-async-sugar.js'
        ],

        jspm: {
            config: 'jspm.conf.js',
            loadFiles: ['src/app/app.js', 'src/app/**/*.spec.js'], //'src/app/**/!(*.e2e|*.po).js'
            serveFiles: ['src/app/**/*.+(js|html|css|json)'] // *.{a,b,c} to *.+(a|b|c) https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1532
        },

        proxies: {
            '/test/': '/base/test/',
            '/src/app/': '/base/src/app/',
            '/jspm_packages/': '/base/jspm_packages/'
        },

        //reporters: process.argv.slice(2).find((argv) => argv.includes('--nocoverage') || argv.includes('--no-coverage')) ? ['dots', 'junit'] : ['dots', 'junit', 'coverage'],

        // use dots reporter, as Travis terminal does not support escaping sequences;
        // when using Travis publish coverage to coveralls
        reporters: coveralls ? ['dots', 'junit', 'coverage', 'coveralls'] : nocoverage ? ['dots'] : ['dots', 'junit', 'coverage'],

        junitReporter: {
            outputDir: 'test-reports/unit-test-report/',
            suite: 'unit'
        },

        preprocessors: {
            // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for - do not include tests or libraries
            // (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
            'src/**/!(*.spec|*.mock|*-mock|*.e2e|*.po|*.test).js': ['babel', 'coverage']
        },

        // transpile with babel since the coverage reporter throws error on ES6 syntax
        babelPreprocessor: {
            options: {
                stage: 1,
                sourceMap: 'inline'
            }
        },

        coverageReporter: {
            instrumenters: { isparta : require('isparta') },
            instrumenter: {
                'src/**/*.js': 'isparta'
            },
            dir: 'test-reports/coverage/',
            subdir: normalizationBrowserName,
            reporters: [
                {type: 'html'}, // will generate html report
                {type: 'json'}, // will generate json report file and this report is loaded to make sure failed coverage cause gulp to exit non-zero
                {type: 'lcov'}, // will generate Icov report file and this report is published to coveralls
                {type: 'text-summary'} // it does not generate any file but it will print coverage to console
            ]
        },

        browsers: [process.env.TRAVIS ? 'Firefox' : 'Chrome'],

        browserNoActivityTimeout: 50000
    });

    function normalizationBrowserName(browser) {
        return browser.toLowerCase().split(/[ /-]/)[0];
    }
};
```

**package.json:**

```
"karma": "0.13.14",
"karma-jspm": "2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "0.3.6",
"karma-coverage": "douglasduteil/karma-coverage#next",
"karma-coveralls": "1.1.2",
"karma-ie-launcher": "0.2.0",
"karma-junit-reporter": "0.3.8",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.1",
"karma-safari-launcher": "0.1.1",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "0.1.6",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "0.2.1",
"karma-babel-preprocessor": "5.2.2"
```

**test-unit.js:**

```
 gulp.task('karma', (cb) => {
    // remove 'coverage' directory before each test
    del.sync(path.test.testReports.coverage);
    // run the karma test
    const server = new Server({
        configFile: path.test.config.karma,
        browsers: BROWSERS.split(','),
        singleRun: !argv.watch,
        autoWatch: !!argv.watch
    }, function(code) {
        // make sure failed karma tests cause gulp to exit non-zero
        if(code === 1) {
            LOG(COLORS.red('Error: unit test failed '));
            return process.exit(1);
        }
        cb();
    });
    server.start();
});
```

**Error:**

> [08:44:36] 'karma' errored after 2.48 s [08:44:36] Error: ENFILE: file
>   table overflow, scandir '/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/src/app'
>   at Error (native) at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:808:18) at
>   GlobSync._readdir
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/sync.js:275:41)
>   at GlobSync._processGlobStar
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/sync.js:330:22)
>   at GlobSync._process
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/sync.js:128:10)
>   at new GlobSync
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/sync.js:46:10)
>   at new Glob
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/glob/glob.js:111:12)
>   at
>   /Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/lib/file-list.js:161:14
>   at Array.map (native) at [object Object].List._refresh
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/lib/file-list.js:153:37)
>   at [object Object].List.refresh
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/lib/file-list.js:252:27)
>   at [object Object].Server._start
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:177:12)
>   at [object Object].invoke
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
>   at [object Object].Server.start
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:101:18)
>   at Gulp.
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/gulp/tasks/test-unit.js:53:12) at
>   module.exports
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator.start
>   (/Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
>   at
>   /Users/Abhi/Documents/projects/test/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
>   at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9) at process._tickCallback
>   (node.js:348:13)

Karma Issue Tracker: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1979

Comment: I've just started to get the same thing today too...  I recently updated JSPM to v0.16.30. Any recent changes on your side that might help narrow the cause? 

Interestingly i've just asked my colleague to test the same code on his and it worked...

The only difference is our OS - Me:Yosemite and him: El Capitan.

Comment: Hi Kevin - I am running El Capitan and on "jspm": "0.16.13" and yes even my colleague is able to run it but he is in Yosemite.I think i did npm or jspm install then it showed up but it won't go even if i reverted, cleaned my node_modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abhi,

I spent a good afternoon on this and found a workaround, to what i have admit is a best guess issue that i have zero idea WHY is happening.

My issue was with the globs inside of serveFiles and loadFiles in the Karma config. To fix i did my own globbing using glob.sync to generate the arrays as i needed and this WORKED!

```
module.exports = function(config) {

    var options = {cwd:"www"};
    var glob = require("glob");
    var filesToServe = glob.sync("./src/**/*.@(js|ts|css|scss|html)", options);
    var specsToLoad = glob.sync("./src/**/*.@(spec.ts)", options).map(function(file){
        return file.substr(2);
    });

    config.set({
        basePath: 'www',

        frameworks: ['jspm', 'jasmine'],

        jspm: {
            config: './test/config.js',
            loadFiles: ['test/boot.ts'].concat(specsToLoad),
            serveFiles: filesToServe,
        },

        files: [
        'http://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-8.2.min.js'
        ],

        proxies: {
            '/src/': '/base/src/',
            '/.test/': '/base/.test/'
        },

        port: 9876,

        logLevel: config.LOG_DISABLE,

        colors: true,

        autoWatch: true,

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        plugins: [
            'karma-jspm',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-spec-reporter'
        ],

        reporters: ['spec'],

        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

The filesToServe and specsToLoad are treated slightly differently, i needed to remove the ./ from the files to load as it interferes with SystemJS's loading internally (this can be recognised by it trying to load a .ts.js file). Also i've got my work in a sub folder, 'www' which you might not need e.g. remove the cwd.

Hopefully you can see what i've done here and it helps you find a workaround. If anyone knows why something like glob is breaking i'd love to know.

To prove it was glob i did a simple test, using

```
require(glob)("src/**/*",function(file){ console.log(file); });
```

This triggered the same error, clearly NOTHING to do with too many files or a file table issue. If this pops up in other places, i'm going to have to clean install the OS again i think. However in my code base i use globs in other places, without any issue. I had wondered if it perhaps was the difference between using the 'sync' version of the process...

A day of wading through options to end up here... i had hoped to find a better answer.

K

Comment: Kevin, my man - you just made my day :) That was funny as i was thinking about the same from a comment from Karma team about this glob issue. I tried with glob-array but its the same

Comment: var globArray = require("glob-array");
 var loadFiles = globArray.sync(['src/app/app.js', 'src/app/**/*.spec.js']);
 var serveFiles = globArray.sync(['src/app/**/*.+(js|html|css|json)']);

Comment: I've recently re-visited the branch that had this bug, and a ```jspm install``` makes it go away. Must be resolved.